# Error implementing Jquery Cycle Plugin

Tags: jquery, magento, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I have been trying to implement many types of slider onto my magento store but I am getting a error each time I am trying to do it. Its very simple error but I am still not being able to rectify it.

Please check this page and let me know why the slider is not working I have called all the necessary plugins and js scripts but its still showing me the error.

www.pennysave.com.au/test

Please help me I am really running out of time and I need to start off with the store asap.

Comment: the html markup is missing actually for which the cycle plugin  has to operate

Comment: Hi refhat, just to make the thing simple I copied the code directly from the plugin website bt still its not working and there is a html markup for that. please <div id="slideshow".... in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have this code in your page.

```
$(function() {
    $('#slideshow img:first').fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $('#slideshow').cycle();
    });
});
```

And I don't see `#slideshow` container at all on the page. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: If you go through the code and analyze it from Google chrome developer tools or firefox firebug. the only error its showing that the code cannot load the method .fadeIn. But I already called the .js in the header and I also have the html markup for the slide as 

`<div id="slideshow" class="pics">
<img src="media/slide1.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="media/slide2.jpg" alt="" /> 
<img src="media/slide3.jpg" alt="" />
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Using $ may conflict with prototype library.
Here is the approach that i follow while including jQuery plugins:
1> Include jQuery file in only required pages using layout updates as:

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <block type="core/text" name="google.cdn.jquery">
            <action method="setText">
                <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>]]>
                </text>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

2> Then include the jQuery Plugin just after the jQuery inclusion
3> Use jQuery instead of $ in your initialization code. 
For example:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('#slideshow img:first').fadeIn(1000, function() {
        jQuery('#slideshow').cycle();
    });
});
```

Hope this helps a bit.
Thanks